# MySQL Sum(if)) grouping

Tags: mysql

I have the following unloaded table:
payment_date,
user_id,
monthlyAmount_last30d

user id and payment date are taken from the table. And in the `monthlyAmount_last30d field`, I want to see the amount for the period (payment date - 30 days).

I can't figure out how to group the columns correctly for such a result. If I group them only by `user_id`, then I see only one first row with the payment date (I need all the rows, each of which will have the ***sum of payments for this user_id for the period (the payment date in the row - 30 days***).
And if I group by both fields -> I get the payment amount always equal to the payment in this line, and not the real amount for the period I need.

```
select
order_id,
order_date,
sum( if( ( order_date <= order_date 
         and order_date >= order_date - interval 30 day), order_cost_rub, 0)) monthlyAmount_last30d,
user_id,
order_cost_rub

from MyTable

group by
user_id
```

Thanks for any tips!

UPD:

Data sample:

| user_id | payment_date | order_cost_rub |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 12:00:00 | 100 |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 13:00:00 | 100 |
| 1 | 2022-01-03 20:00:00 | 150 |
| 2 | 2022-01-03 16:00:00 | 200 |
| 2 | 2022-01-15 11:00:00 | 300 |

expected result:

| user_id | payment_date | order_cost_rub | monthlyAmount_last30d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 12:00:00 | 100 | 100 |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 13:00:00 | 100 | 200 |
| 1 | 2022-01-03 20:00:00 | 150 | 350 |
| 2 | 2022-01-03 16:00:00 | 200 | 200 |
| 2 | 2022-01-15 11:00:00 | 300 | 500 |

Comment: order_date <= order_date  ??  I don't tjhink this can be correct did you mean order_date <= current_date

Comment: Please add sample data and expected outcome as text

Comment: Hello! Thank you! The fact is that in my case, curdate() does not suit me (today minus 30 days). I want to still see the row with each payment, and in the sum column I want to see the amount of payments from that day minus 30 days (from the payment date in this row, not from today). I have completed my question.

Comment: Looks like you want a cumulative sum if you are on mysql 8 or  above use sum() over window function if you are not then state what version you are on.

Comment: version 5.7.25  .

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is incorrect in the IF().  I think what you are asking for should be applied in the WHERE clause, such as

I want all record transactions for all people that have happened within the last 30 days.  From that, I want the total of all their purchases and grouped with totals per each person.  Sound about right?

```
select
      user_id,
      payment_date,
      order_cost_rub,
      sum( order_cost_rub ) 
         OVER ( PARTITION BY user_id 
                order by payment_date ) AS monthlyAmount_last30d
   from 
      MyTable
   where
      order_date >= subdate(curdate(), interval 30 day)
```

By applying the query WHERE clause, you are never getting ANY transactions prior to it, so no need to apply an IF() condition check on every record.

Revised query. So, you want EVERY record to show but going back 30 days.  So, the WHERE clause really can still be applicable.  But now I am showing all the columns per normal record.  Look at the SUM(). This is doing a running total what you are looking for.

Notice the OVER clause after it (I indented just to show context it was associated with the sum() process.  The OVER states what partioning (group by, but not a normal outer group by).  This just means to start over whenever this partition value changes.  In this case, the user ID.  And to kick in the rest, the ORDER BY also within the partition indicates to order the data in payment_date order.

I think this should get what you need.

Comment: Thank you! I have made additions to my question, unfortunately, the option with curdate() does not suit me

Comment: @Kitsune.Dark, see revised answer